# SoapUI steps overwrites log4j settings

Tags: maven, log4j, soapui, jbehave

I'm having a setup where I run JBehave tests during a Maven build.

Test steps include sending requests to a web service with the SoapUI Java classes.

Everything is working fine, testwise. My problem is that the SoapUI part of the progress seems to overwrite the log4j settings so that subsequent log calls doesn't get printed to console (nor files).

I've tried the workaround where I call

```
    ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    URL resource = loader.getResource("log4j.xml");
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(resource);
```

to try to reset the configuration to my original one, but no success so far.

Log4j (1.2) and SoapUI (4.5.1) uses plain settings in pom. The logger is created as
`protected final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());`

The console output I get follows:

```
    pool-1-thread-1 16:36:08,212 DEBUG ästeps.LoginSteps:25 - logging in user: testfir
    pool-1-thread-1 16:36:08,213 DEBUG äpages.LoginPage:26 - Create LoginPage
    pool-1-thread-1 16:36:08,985 DEBUG äpages.LoginPage:38 - login user: testfir
    pool-1-thread-1 16:36:10,343 DEBUG äpages.WorkspacePage:36 - creating WorkspacePage
    Givet user testfir has logged in
    16:36:11,634 WARN  [SoapUI] Missing folder [D:\proj\src\test\functional-tests\.\ext] for external libraries
    16:36:11,809 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] initialized soapui-settings from [C:\Users\xxx\soapui-settings.xml]
    16:36:12,176 INFO  [WsdlProject] Loaded project from [file:/D:/proj/src/test/functional-tests/src/test/resources/ReceiveCase-soapui.xml]
    16:36:12,640 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
    16:36:12,640 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /soa-infra/services/default/ReceiveCases/ReceiveCase_v1_0_ep HTTP/1.1
    16:36:13,841 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    16:36:13,842 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
    And a case exists
    When case is choosen
    16:36:46,832 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection closed
    Then the details are displyed
```

And I'm expecting a log output with

> Setting case Id to: 123456

in the same manner as "Create login page".

Can't understand why this is and what to do to get my log entries to show up. Any ideas out there?

Best regards, Christian

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the root of the problem.
It was Maven that distorted the file encoding. Adding

> ```
>     <configuration>
>       <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
>       <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
>       <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
>       <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
>     </configuration>
> ```

to the `maven-surefire-plugin` part in pom file solved my issue.

/Cheers